# Gradient Equations as a system of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

I was trying to understand Eq(3) of [1] and was a bit overwhelmed by matrix related short-hand notations to make the equation concise.

### Eq (3)

> Let $W_i \in \mathbb{R}^{d_{i-1} \times d_i}$, $W = W_{H+1} \dots W_1$, $U^\top_i = \prod^{H+1}_{j = i + 1} W^\top_j$, and $V^\top_i = \prod^{i-1}_{j = 1} W^\top_j$.
> And the objective function $L(W) = \bar{L}(W) + \lambda \sum^{H+1}_{i=1} || W_i ||^2_2$ with $\bar{L}(W) = \frac{1}{2} \sum^m_{i=1} || (W X)_{\cdot, i} - Y_{\cdot, i} ||^2_2 $.

Then, it states that we can obtain the following partial derivative as a system of polynomials

> $\frac{\partial L}{\partial W_i} = U^\top_i \big( W \big( \sum^m_{k=1} x_k x^\top_k \big) - \big( \sum^m_{k=1} y_k x^\top_k \big) \big) V^\top_i + \frac{\lambda}{2} W_i$

But it doesn't have the derivation... can someone prove this?

### reference

[1] Mehta, Dhagash, et al. "The loss surface of deep linear networks viewed through the algebraic geometry lens." IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence 44.9 (2021): 5664-5680. [Paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.07716.pdf)

Comment: The term involving $\lambda$ is obviously incorrect since
$$
\frac{\partial\left(\lambda\|A\|^2_2\right)}{\partial A}
 = 2\lambda A
$$
Are you sure the remaining terms were transcribed correctly?

Comment: yeah, I was thinking about it too. there is a link to the paper in my post so you can cross-check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a partial product function
$$\eqalign{
\def\p{\partial} \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\l{\bar L}
\def\R{\right}
\def\L{\left}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\trace{\operatorname{Tr}}
P(i,j) &= \begin{cases}
{\displaystyle\prod_{k=i}^{j}}\;W_k \quad {\rm if}\;i\ge j \\
\\
\;I \qquad\quad {\rm otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
}$$
and use it to expand the differential of $W$
$$\eqalign{
W &= P(H,\o) \qiq
dW &= \sum_{k=H}^{\o}P(H,k+\o)\cdot dW_k\cdot P(k-\o,\o) \\
}$$
$\sf NB$:$\,$ In the above, I redefined $(H+\o)\to H$ because it's a dumb notation that just adds visual clutter to the problem.

The Frobenius product will also be very useful
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_j\sum_k A_{jk}B_{jk} \;=\; \trace(A^TB) \\
A:A &= \L\|A\R\|^2_F \\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
(AB):C &= A:(CB^T) \;=\; B:(A^TC) \\
}$$
For typing convenience, define the matrix
$$M = WXX^T-YX^T$$
The $\l$ part of the cost function can be differentiated as
$$\eqalign{
\l &= \tfrac12 \L(WX-Y\R):\L(WX-Y\R) \\
d\l &= \L(WX-Y\R):\L(dW\,X\R) \\
 &= \L(WXX^T-YX^T\R):dW \\
 &= M:\L(\sum_{k=H}^{\o}P(H,k+\o)\cdot dW_k\cdot P(k-\o,\o)\R) \\
 &= \sum_{k=H}^{\o}P(H,k+\o)^T\cdot M\cdot P(k-\o,\o)^T:\,dW_k \\
}$$
Since we're only interested in the $dW_k$ component, drop the summation to obtain
$$\eqalign{
d\l &= P(H,k+\o)^T\cdot M\cdot P(k-\o,\o)^T:\,dW_k \\
\grad{\l}{W_k} &= P(H,k+\o)^T\cdot M\cdot P(k-\o,\o)^T \\
}$$

---

As you delve further into the field of Machine Learning / Neural Networks, you will discover that most of the books and journal articles use **poor** mathematical notation (including those by respected researchers). Worse, it is inconsistent from author to author.  Good luck!

A simple example from the current article
$$YX^T = \sum_k y_kx_k^T$$

Comment: thank you so much for compiling the detailed answer! Unfortunately, I'm on an urgent task today.... but will be getting back to this tomorrow!

Comment: I've looked through your answer and bit of review of matrix calculus regaring inner product, now it all makes sense! Thank you so much!